# HTML representation of '»'

Tags: html, character

I'm looking for the HTML notation for `»`.

I found &#x226b, but that gives `≫`, not the smaller `»`?

Comment: They're called [guillemets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `&raquo;` as found [here](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php)